# Aditional Detail for Computer Object also

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

With Acctinfo.dll we get an additional Detail for User Object such as ( please see the below screen )[image]

Is it possible for Computer object also such as Last user login...etc

Comment: As I recall, the Computer class is a subclass of either User or Person

Answer (score 0):

It sure is.

I'd recommend using a "proper" tool or script to do so, but any AD object can be queried for any attribute that exists in your schema, and Computer objects do use the lastLogon attributes.  I'd use PowerShell and the AD module to do it if I had to do it for more than one object, but below is a screenshot from `ADSIedit.msc` of the first computer I clicked on.

[image: Computer AD Attriubutes]